# How to input long paragraphs in a table without it getting out of document

Tags: tables, alignment

The image below shows how the text is going out and I need to add more text, basically long descriptions

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CharisSIL}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=0.5in,left=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Speaker 1 & Speaker 2 & Speaker 3\\
        \hline
        Central Gujarat & North Gujarat & East Gujarat\\
        The first speaker is talking about the language in a more constricted manner & The second speaker does not really care about the pronunciation but you can see the variation in the vowels & WHat about the third speaker to make sure that her rules are nor interchanging with someone else\\
        \hline  
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How do I fix this and add more text in my columns? Also how can I adjust the entire thing as per the text width?

Comment: Look up the `tabularx` package

Answer (score 2):

**Standard tabular environment with columns of a specified width**
Use `p{width}` as column specifier.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
        \hline
        Speaker 1 & Speaker 2 & Speaker 3\\
        \hline
        Central Gujarat & North Gujarat & East Gujarat\\
        The first speaker is talking about the language in a more constricted manner & The second speaker does not really care about the pronunciation but you can see the variation in the vowels & What about the third speaker to make sure that her rules are nor interchanging with someone else\\
        \hline  
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**tabularx environment with columns of maximal width, auto-expanding**
Load the `tabularx` package, add the width of the table (probably `\textwidth`) and use the column specifier `X`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        Speaker 1 & Speaker 2 & Speaker 3\\
        \hline
        Central Gujarat & North Gujarat & East Gujarat\\
        The first speaker is talking about the language in a more constricted manner & The second speaker does not really care about the pronunciation but you can see the variation in the vowels & What about the third speaker to make sure that her rules are nor interchanging with someone else\\
        \hline  
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

You can center the headers using `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Speaker 1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Speaker 2} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Speaker 3}\\
        \hline
        Central Gujarat & North Gujarat & East Gujarat\\
        The first speaker is talking about the language in a more constricted manner & The second speaker does not really care about the pronunciation but you can see the variation in the vowels & What about the third speaker to make sure that her rules are nor interchanging with someone else\\
        \hline  
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```